# How to connect Neo4j JDBC driver with DbVisualizer

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, dbvisualizer

I am running Neo4j 2.1.6, tried Neo4j 2.20 as well.
I can not connect it with DbVisualizer 9.1.13

And I can not find ANY step by step clear explanation on how to do it.

First I've got binary JDBC Neo4j-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT [here](http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-jdbc/neo4j-jdbc-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

I can run my just installed Neo4j instance from the browser localhost:7474
and I don't know what the REST API is all about and if it is turned on by default.

I can run the Neo4j 2.20 same way that comes with a new feature of user authorization and I am not sure if that JDBC driver is compatible with it. My user:pass is neo4j:neo

So in DbVisualizer I clicked Tools->Driver Manager and filled out like this:

[image: Driver Manager]

My connection properties are as follows:

[image: Connection properties]

I've got the error on connect:

Product:  DbVisualizer Pro 9.1.13

Build:  #2310 (2015-01-11 11:26:27)

Java Version:  1.8.0_25

OS Name:  Windows Server 2012 R2

An error occurred while establishing the connection:
The selected Driver cannot handle the specified Database URL.
The most common reason for this error is that the database URL
contains a syntax error preventing the driver from accepting it.
The error also occurs when trying to connect to a database
with the wrong driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for the jdbc driver](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc#minimum-viable-snippet), you see that the database URL is:

```
jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/
```

Please try to make it work with 2.1.6 first.

For the 2.2. auth you have to use the token you got back as **password**.

[image]

Comment: What about with jDTS driver [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968956/which-db-driver-to-use-dbvisualiser-with-azure-sql)? I don't know whether it is a correct driver but I am trying to use it with Azure SQL db but getting errs with url of the format `myDb.database.windows.net`.